# useEffect with async and Cookies.get in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, async-await, next.js, use-effect, js-cookie

I'm trying to get cookie data in use effect and then use that data, my component looks like this..

```
const Favourites = (props) => {
  const [isClick, setClick] = useState(false);

  const activityId = props.activityId

  useEffect(() => {
    const favourites = Cookies.get('favourites')
    if (favourites[activityId] === true) {
      setClick(true)
    }
  })

  return (
    <>
      <div className="heart">
        <Heart isClick={isClick} onClick={() => setClick(!isClick)} />
      </div>

    </>
  );
}
```

this is what I get when I console.log(Cookies.get('favourites')) -

```
{"5edf47240dcb4713d3942e1b":true,"5edf47240dcb4713d3942e2b":true,"5fa10bd8f70458050ffe68af":true}
```

changing

```
const favourites = Cookies.get('favourites')
```

to

```
const favourites = {"5edf47240dcb4713d3942e1b":true,"5edf47240dcb4713d3942e2b":true,"5fa10bd8f70458050ffe68af":true}
```

produces the desired effect.

favourites is an array of activityID's stored in localstorage using js-cookie. it's basically a list of the users favourite activities, if they like the activity and click the heart button then the activityID is stored as the key and the value is set to true

the above doesn't work, setClick isn't being set to true if the activityId is true in the favourites array. If I console.log(Cookies.get('favourites')) and copy the result into const favourites then it does work

Comment: What's `activityId` (a state value maybe? beware of it being a missing dependency then) and which lib do you use for `Cookies`?

Comment: Can you also paste what's in `favourites`

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what *it does not work* exactly means?

Comment: With `activityId` coming from props, you need it as a dependency to `useEffect`. Also `Cookies.get` is synchronous, so the whole `async/await` is superfluous.

Comment: I believe you just need to do a `JSON.decode` on that

Comment: JSON.parse worked @Victor

Comment: Going to post the answer, just for brevity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your edit, it looks like what `console.log` is showing is actually a `string`. So, doing a `JSON.decode` on what `Cookies.get` is returning should do the trick:

```js
const favourites = JSON.decode(Cookies.get('favourites'));
```